# DBFlow - Gradle cannot find symbol DatabaseHolder when using multiple modules

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, build.gradle

i need help with a problem using DBFlow 4.0.0-beta3 and Gradle 2.2.3 in my module app of an Android Studio project; i have two modules (app, notifications) that uses DBFlow so i configure them like is indicated in the [usage](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage2/MultipleModules.md) of the library, the notifications module compiles whell and generates the DatabaseHolder class, then the compiler goes to app and throws the exception:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.SamsungGeneratedDatabaseHolder;
```

But that class is generated successfully, this is my gradle output:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :notifications:generateDebugSources, :notifications:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :notifications:mockableAndroidJar, :notifications:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :notifications:compileDebugSources, :notifications:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :notifications:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :sapservice:generateDebugSources, :sapservice:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :sapservice:mockableAndroidJar, :sapservice:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :sapservice:compileDebugSources, :sapservice:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :sapservice:compileDebugUnitTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:notifications:clean
:sapapi:clean
:sapprocessor:clean
:sapservice:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:checkReleaseManifest
:notifications:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42511Library
:notifications:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2511Library
:notifications:prepareComGithubRaizlabsDBFlowDbflow400Beta3Library
:notifications:prepareComGithubRaizlabsDBFlowDbflowKotlinextensions400Beta3Library
:notifications:prepareIoReactivexRxjava2Rxandroid201Library
:notifications:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda2942Library
:notifications:prepareReleaseDependencies
:notifications:compileReleaseAidl
:notifications:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:compileLint
:notifications:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:compileReleaseRenderscript
:notifications:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:notifications:generateReleaseResValues
:notifications:generateReleaseResources
:notifications:mergeReleaseResources
:notifications:processReleaseManifest
:notifications:processReleaseResources
:notifications:generateReleaseSources
:notifications:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:notifications:compileReleaseKotlin
:notifications:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Destination for generated sources was modified by kapt. Previous value = /home/diego/Documents/development/mobile/android/samsung-club/notifications/build/generated/source/apt/release
:notifications:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.NotificationsRegisterDatabaseNotificationsRegisterDatabase_Database' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.NotificationsModuleGeneratedDatabaseHolder' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
2 warnings

:notifications:compileReleaseKotlinAfterJava
:notifications:copyReleaseKotlinClasses
:notifications:extractReleaseAnnotations
:notifications:mergeReleaseShaders
:notifications:compileReleaseShaders
:notifications:generateReleaseAssets
:notifications:mergeReleaseAssets
:notifications:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:packageReleaseResources
:notifications:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:notifications:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:notifications:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:notifications:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:notifications:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:notifications:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:notifications:bundleRelease
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2511Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2511Library
:app:prepareComAppsflyerAfAndroidSdk467Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers136Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta114Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics255Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore238Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsNdk111Library
:app:prepareComDaimajiaSwipelayoutLibrary120Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk470Library
:app:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0857Library
:app:prepareComGithubRaizlabsDBFlowDbflow400Beta3Library
:app:prepareComGithubRaizlabsDBFlowDbflowKotlinextensions400Beta3Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid961Library
:app:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils043Library
:app:prepareComKarumiDexter231Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetComposer200Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTweetUi200Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitter200Library
:app:prepareComTwitterSdkAndroidTwitterCore200Library
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1313Library
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid121Library
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxjava2Rxandroid201Library
:app:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary115Library
:app:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda2942Library
:app:prepareSamsungClubGeoreferencedpushnotificationsReleaseUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareSamsungClubNotificationsUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/diego/Documents/development/mobile/android/samsung-club/app/google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/home/diego/Documents/development/mobile/android/samsung-club/app/src/main/java/com/creardigitalm/samsungclub/controller/fragment/MyBenefitsFragment.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.SamsungGeneratedDatabaseHolder;
                                         ^
  symbol:   class SamsungGeneratedDatabaseHolder
  location: package com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config
warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.SamsungClubDatabaseSamsungDB_Database' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.SamsungGeneratedDatabaseHolder' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
1 error
2 warnings

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.914 secs
```

Like you can see the compiler try to find the import class and then generate the classes i will post my app gradle.build (i switch from apt to annotationProcessor):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creardigitalm.samsungclub"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 69
        versionName '1.5.5.0'
        //multiDexEnabled true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [ targetModuleName : 'Samsung']
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue("bool", "is_debug", "true")
        }
        release {
            resValue("bool", "is_debug", "false")

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    packagingOptions {
        //exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

/*apt {
    arguments {
        targetModuleName 'Samsung'
    }
}*/


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    /*---- GOOGLE SUPPORT LIBRARIES ----*/
    // MATERIAL DESIGN
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"

    // PERCENT RELATIVE LAYOUT
    compile "com.android.support:percent:${support_version}"

    //MATERIAL DIALOGS
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    /*----------------------------------*/

    //SWIPE LIST
    // Swipe layout https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"

    //PICASSO
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


    /*------ DEPENDENCY INJECTION ------*/
    // ButterKnife utils http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    // Parceler https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.4'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------- REST - NETWORKING -------*/
    // Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    // OkHttp http://square.github.io/okhttp/
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------------ GOOGLE --------------*/
    //Google Map Utils.
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
    //Google Cloud Message
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
    //Google Location
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    //Google Maps
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    //Google Analytics
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------------ FABRIC --------------*/
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*----------- ANALYTICS ------------*/
    //Appsflyer
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------------ FACEBOOK ------------*/
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------------- TWITTER -------------*/
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*--------- GEO FENCED PUSH --------*/
    compile project(':georeferencedpushnotifications-release')
    /*compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.2'
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-kotlinextensions:$dbflow_version"*/
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*---------- NOTIFICATIONS ---------*/
    compile project(':notifications')
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------------ SECURITY ------------*/
    // Dexter https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*--------------- RX ---------------*/
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------------ MULTIDEX ------------*/
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*-------------- DBFLOW ------------*/
    annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:$dbflow_version"

    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:$dbflow_version"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:$dbflow_version"
    /*----------------------------------*/

    /*------- SAPAPI PARA GEAR S2 ------*/
    /*compile project(':sapservice')
    apt project(':sapprocessor')
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5'*/
    /*----------------------------------*/
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```